# Trying to change image DPI without changing file size

Tags: c#, bitmap, dpi

I have the following code for changing the DPI of an image:

```
public void changeDPI(string imagePathSource,string imagePathDestination,float DPIx,float DPIy)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imagePathSource);
            Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap);
            newBitmap.SetResolution(DPIx,DPIy);
            newBitmap.Save(imagePathDestination);
        }
```

However, this ends up changing the memory size of the file.  An example test image started at 267 KB, and the `newBitmap` version of the file ended up as 1.51 MB.  How can I change the DPI without changing the file size?

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance here in how this works.. but why would it not change the file size?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb [The Truth About Image Resolution, File Size and the Web](https://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/the-truth-about-image-resolution-and-file-size-in-photoshop/)

Comment: My guess is that `imagePathSource` is a compressed format like .jpg or .png. `Bitmap.Save` with no format specified saves as an uncompressed .bmp.

Comment: Thanks for the article @user1538301

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Np, you had the exact same question as me.

Comment: @DourHighArch, yeah, I'm trying to change the resolution on a jpg.  Peyman Mahdavi's answer addresses this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must indicate the format of the output file, to save as a compressed image format like JPEG.

```
newBitmap.Save(imagePathDestination, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you making a new bitmap out of it? That converts the image to 32bpp ARGB, and loses the connection to the original loaded data.

The original loaded image's file format is available in the `RawFormat` property. So just set the original bitmap's resolution to your new one, and save it to the new path using `bitmap.RawFormat`:

```
public void changeDPI(String imagePathSource, String imagePathDestination, Single dpiX, Single dpiY)
{
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imagePathSource))
    {
        bitmap.SetResolution(dpiX, dpiY);
        bitmap.Save(imagePathDestination, bitmap.RawFormat);
    }
}
```

I believe that this way, it won't even recompress the actual image content, meaning you have no further quality degrading due to reapplying the jpeg compression.

Also, do make sure you always either call `Dispose()` on image objects, or use them in a `using` block. They are objects backed by unmanaged sources (GDI+ objects), so you have to be careful or they'll pollute your program's memory, and keep locks on the files you opened.

On the note of locked files, if you give the same path for both `imagePathSource` and `imagePathDestination` you'll get an error about exactly that. To get around this, read the bytes from the image in advance, and use a MemoryStream to load the image:

```
public void changeDPI(String imagePathSource, String imagePathDestination, Single dpiX, Single dpiY)
{
    Byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllbytes(imagePathSource);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileData))
    using (Bitmap loadedImage = new Bitmap(ms))
    {
        bitmap.SetResolution(dpiX, dpiY);
        bitmap.Save(imagePathDestination, bitmap.RawFormat);
    }
}
```